# Как сгенерировать ссылку на XML файл через Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive

Есть `XML` файл сохраненный в `Google Drive`.
Как вывести его содержимое через `Google Apps Script`, чтоб отображалось содержимое `XML` файла без самого интерфейса `Google Apps Script`?
Вот как [по этой ссылке](https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=Ie5qS7sAzQw5Kbb9fveEkOEnp-M5A6mxFUEjgFF5iXyVDyXt6Y01YFXjIPlr6HsYXEA8-fNpwbZLtv7nw2j42jWNiyttGts8m5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnOfRnxRdBrHV329Cc-_8MQnjQnW54R7dGsqJBygAo11UX28AtJfyVPCvE9TuQ_1-8tpytj_A4aoE&lib=MZNxtxdz8c4esnFX0ZHZCsxjq1OGlSjhT) выводится XML.
Как имея `XML` файл сгенерировать такую ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо использовать [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)

```
function doGet(){
  var content = DriveApp.getFileById("ID").getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var cs = ContentService.createTextOutput(content)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
  return cs;
}
```

Comment: вот, например, есть ссылка на гугл диск на хмл https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JzLLLMdwDBuik0fXmU-ZEPB-tvMACcde/view куда ее вставить в Вашем коде?

Comment: Замените `ID` на `1JzLLLMdwDBuik0fXmU-ZEPB-tvMACcde`

Comment: супер! Спасибо работает